# Notification alert is audible... but what is causing the notification?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, notification

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with the GNOME 3.28.2 graphical shell. With headphones on and listening to some soft music, I can hear an occasional notification alert "ping"... but I cannot figure out what generated the alert or what action(s) trigger the alert. The alert(s) appear to happen randomly every few minutes.

The notification tray area (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or click the clock) only lists the music I'm listening to and nothing else. Is there some system log file that lists events that triggered an audible alert?